# How to use border radius only for 1 corner (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to use border radius in React Native only for 1 corner?

I have a modal window

[image: http://f1.s.qip.ru/etSMz5YP.png]

As you can see bottom corners not rounded, it happens when I used backgroundColor for buttons. I was trying to set overflow hidden to modal wrapper and it didn't help me. Now I want to use border radius to buttons (only for 1 corner).

My code http://jsbin.com/sexeputuqe/edit?html,css

Comment: I don't know about reactjs but you can use the `border-top/bottom-left/right-radius` CSS property (eg. `border-bottom-right-radius: 5px`)

Comment: Big UI problem: "Pressing Cancel will XYZ", but there is no cancel button. Also, "Yes" appears to correspond to a destructive action. I strongly suggest changing the button labels to "Discard" (which should also be on the left) and "Keep".

Comment: Can you share your code and styling for the element? I think I may know what's happening here. Thanks.

Comment: My code http://jsbin.com/sexeputuqe/edit?html,css

Comment: Excuse me, but for you to get your desired effect you can use `overflow: 'hidden'` in the parent view of the buttons

Comment: I does work for me with `overflow: 'hidden' in the parent view, but in my case that will remove its shadow.

Comment: `borderRadius: 5, overflow: 'hidden'` for the container worked for me

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Did you already try with the following?
 - `borderBottomLeftRadius`: number
 - `borderBottomRightRadius`: number
 - `borderTopLeftRadius`: number
 - `borderTopRightRadius`: number

Also, you can find more info in [the view component docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html).

Comment: Yes, I was trying it, but had no effect.

Comment: Did you have the correct selector for whatever DOM elements that React creates?

Comment: In your example, if the two buttons are in the question box, you need to set border radius on the button and the container. If not then using borderBottomLeftRadius and borderBottomRightRadius should do the trick. Something like `borderBottomLeftRadius: 5` on the No button and `borderBottomRightRadius: 5` on the Yes button. If this doesn't work, maybe provide us a sample of your code so we can check that nothing else interferes.

Comment: does not work for me either on IOS. only `borderRadius` will work but apply a radius to all corners

Comment: @kevin the iOS version of the `Image` component [ignores corner specific radius settings](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/images.html#ios-border-radius-styles). You can use a negative margin to "mask" off the corners you don't want rounded in some cases.

Comment: try putting `overflow:hidden` to your View(or Text). It should work.

Comment: @Josh Can you add your comment as an answer? It is the answer this question deserves. :)

Comment: @Josh: your link 404s, update: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#ios-border-radius-styles

Comment: This worked on React Native perfectly!

Answer (score 29):

Add the following properties in your style:

- `borderBottomLeftRadius: number`
- `borderBottomRightRadius: number`
- `borderTopLeftRadius: number`
- `borderTopRightRadius: number`

This worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: Add more explanation to the answer.

Comment: @DanielJosePadillaPeña, did you find any solution?

Comment: hardcoding, adding another image without corner, hiding the radius. Is not a good way but still found another solution.

Comment: It works for me, when I added overflow: "hidden" property

Comment: Can anyone tell the difference between "borderTopStartRadius" and "borderTopLeftRadius"?

Answer (score 13):

#### Suppose only the radius is set for the upper left and lower left corners of the Image tag.

```
<View style={styles.imgBox}>
  <Image source={{ uri: 'your image url' }} style={styles.img} />
</View>

 const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
 imgBox: {
       width: px(72),
       height: px(72),
       borderBottomLeftRadius: 2,
       borderTopLeftRadius: 2,
       overflow: 'hidden',
 },
 img: {
       width: px(72),
       height: px(72),
  },
})
```

looks good for ios.

Comment: incomplete - can you please add the required npm packages and missing `import` statements ?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS syntax in react-native is a little different.

Where traditionally you could use:

```
borderRadius:0,0,20,0;
```

where you assign border-radius values clockwise

However in this case you'll have to target individual corners of your element like so:

```
borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
borderTopRightRadius: 0,
borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
```

Please let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, and that is when you only have two or 3 borders and you try to apply radius to one corner, the problem occurs.

To overcome this issue, you have to apply border to all the sides of your component like the following:

```
borderWidth: 1;
borderColor: 'gray';
```

And because in my case, I want to only display top and right borders, I give the left and bottom the color of the background, and take 1 from both marginLeft and marginTop like the following:

```
borderLeftColor: 'white';
borderBottomColor: 'white';
marginLeft: -1;
marginTop: -1;
```

Now If I apply radius to only one corner, it works perfectly:

```
borderTopRightRadius: 6;
```

I hope this helps someone, as it is just a workaround.

Thanks